# Image field theming

Tags: views, entities

In Drupal 6 Views, there was an option to display the path of that file for an image type field, which is not present in Drupal 7.
Where is it?

Comment: Which views version are you using? Are you using the views-7.x-3.x-dev with the new UI?

Comment: 7.x-3.0-alpha1, I also made a fresh install and tried it with -dev. Nothing.

Comment: I ended up using image_style_url() http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--image--image.module/function/image_style_url/7 in row views theming

Comment: You should add that as answer and accept it (when you can), or accept an existing answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Drupal7 the output is handled by the formatter. If you have a formatter which allows to output the filepath it will be used.

In core there is none so the [Custom Formatters](https://www.drupal.org/project/custom_formatters) module will help you. Some more details about this module (from its project page):

> The Custom Formatters module allows users to easily create custom Field Formatters without the need to write a custom module. Custom Formatters can then be exported as CTools Exportables, Features or Drupal API Field Formatters.

Comment: Can you give me an example on how to make a custom formatter and display the file path of an image? I also want to use an imagecache style path